# Automatically embed a URL in a forum topic

Tags: html, embed, invision-power-board

I'm using Invision Community forum software, when I paste a link to a topic or download from the forum, it automatically embeds the topic/post or download.

My forum has the ability to automatically create a topic when a file has been uploaded.
In the automatically created topic content, I would like to show the file embeded. (Exactly the same way as if you should post the URL to the file manually.)

To achieve this, I added this to the automatically created topic

```
{$file->url()}
```

This works, but it just renders the URL, it doesn't embed the file. When you paste the same URL when manually editing the topic, it does embed the file.

So long story short: 
when using {$file->url()} it shows https://example.com but it does not render the file.
when editing the topic and pasting the URL manually, it does embed the file immediately.

Is there something I need to add to my code?